# how variables declared private in javabean get accessed by jsp

Tags: java, private

I have defined many private variables and also defined there getter/setter method and then I'm accessing these variables in jsp page by using expression language.But how privately defined variables gets accessed in jsp page??
My java bean code is-
The variables are

```
                private String beam_current;
                private String beam_energy;
                private String st4_vs6_bag1_rb;
                private String st4_vs6_bag2_rb;
                private String st4_vs6_bag3_rb;
                private String st4_vs6_bag4_rb;
                private String st4_vs6_bag5_rb;
                private String st4_vs6_bag6_rb;
                private String st4_vs6_bag7_rb;
                private String st4_vs6_bag8_rb;
                private String st4_vs6_bag9_rb;
```

There set method is used as-

```
                   while(rs.next()) 
                    {
                     Vacc_vs6 ref_drop=new Vacc_vs6();
                     ref_drop.setLogtime(rs.getString(1));
                     ref_drop.setBeam_current(rs.getString(2));
                     ref_drop.setBeam_energy(rs.getString(3));
                     ref_drop.setst4_vs6_bag1_rb(rs.getString(4));
                     ref_drop.setst4_vs6_bag2_rb(rs.getString(5));
                     ref_drop.setst4_vs6_bag3_rb(rs.getString(6));
                     ref_drop.setst4_vs6_bag4_rb(rs.getString(7));
                     ref_drop.setst4_vs6_bag5_rb(rs.getString(8));
                     ref_drop.setst4_vs6_bag6_rb(rs.getString(9));
                     ref_drop.setst4_vs6_bag7_rb(rs.getString(10));
                     ref_drop.setst4_vs6_bag8_rb(rs.getString(11));
```

There are getter and setter methods defined in the code as-

```
    public String getBeam_current() {
            return beam_current;
        }

        public void setBeam_current(String string) {
            this.beam_current = string;
        }
```

Now my jsp is:-

```
<c:forEach var="r" items="${ref.refernece(param.ref_logtime)}" 

begin="${count}" end="${count}"> 

<tr bgcolor="darkgray ">
<td><c:out value="${r.logtime}"></c:out></td>

<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(r.beam_current) ne 0}">
```

**My query is,how I'm able to access variables beam_current and logtime when they are defined as private in java class??**

Comment: They're accessed through reflection through corresponding `public` getter methods.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis , can you please explain me the full mechanism???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't declared the `getter/setter` as private i guess (you did right).

As long as `getter/setter` are public they are accessible through those method (in a nutshell).

Actually this is one of the basic purpose of these  methods.

You can experiment by making any of them private and access that from expression language then see what happen.

Answer (score 3):

In very simple terms, the following EL expression

```
${r.beam_current}
```

is basically resolved as

```
Object r = servletRequest.getAttribute("r"); // or from page, session, or application attributes
Class<?> clazz = r.getClass(); 
Method getter = clazz.getMethod(resolveName("beam_current")); // where resolvedName generates a getter name through Java Bean property naming conventions
String result = getter.invoke(r);
```

and then `result` is written to the `ServletResponse`'s `OutputStream`.